# Resistors are heating-up

Tags: resistors, vacuum-tube

I'm restoring an old vacuum tube radio, I removed all the bad capacitors, resistors and all 5 vacuum tubes and exchanged them with new ones. Finally, I installed the last two resistors in parallel, as per the schematics, but when I operated the radio both resistors became extremely hot so I put the radio off. Those resistors are installed in parallel and located between the main power transformer of the tube radio and the rectifier tube and their values are 270 ohms/2 watts and 330 ohms/2 watts, exactly as per schematics.  I've also done all the voltage checks and everything appears to be normal. What could be causing both resistors to heat-up?
[image: GE X317]

Comment: Uh, as long as they're not *overheating*, it may be normal. Considering they're specified as 2 watt parts, they probably dissipate > 1 watt in normal operation.

Comment: Any traces that should've/shouldn't have been connected? When components get that hot in my circuits it usually means I connected something wrong

Comment: Perhaps the originals were ceramic wirewound resistors, which operate at elevated temperatures without worry.

Comment: WIthout the schematics no one can tell what they are supposed to be. Do some calculations on what they are likely designed to dissipate

Comment: Also check the specifications to see what the temperature will be at 2 W. I saw someone make that mistake and was very surprised that at 2 W the resistor was fine but operating at about 80°C.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - I have the schematics and I got them as per the schematics but still they are overheating. I think that the originals were ceramic resistors  as gbarry mentioned. I will try  changing them to ceramic ones and see what happens.

Comment: Whether they were ceramic or not has nothing to do with whether they are correct for the circuit.  All that matters is that you have the correct resistance and power rating.

Comment: You are going to have to post the schematic in order to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: A pair of resistors between the PTX and the rectifier doesn't sound right. More likely it should be between the first and second decoupling stages after the rectifier. Check your schematic.

Comment: @Dr. Funk - I've added one page of the schematics. Resistors no. R24 and R25 (highlighted). I apologize for the quality of the schematic, it was printed in the 1950s.

Comment: @gbarry - I've just checked the schematics, the resistors are carbon resistor, not ceramic.

Comment: Those old schematics bring back memories.  And the 6U5 tuning indicator is cool, too.  Best bet here is to figure out how to measure the current through those resistors.  Tricky, since it's not DC (yet), and because of the high voltages involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Measure to assure R18 is 3800 ohms.  If R18 is correct then the problem is in the audio output section for certain.

Regardless of the discussion in comments and answers, the given values (and wattage) in the schematic for R24 and R25 seem to be correct and normal values for this type of radio. My conclusion is based on years of experience restoring radios of this type.

You mentioned that you replaced all of the "bad" capacitors. Hopefully this means that you replaced C36, C42, C300, and C38 in addition to the capacitors you mentioned.

The resistors R15, R19, and R30(?)(470K) set the bias on the output tube. Confirm that these resistor values are also good.

You haven't mentioned whether the radio produces audio output. Also, how much time lapses from power on to the point where you felt the need to turn power off? If the tubes are glowing filaments, then you should hear audio out when on station. At least the hiss between channels.

The possibility of the output transformer (T3) being defective is low. However the components on the secondary,  C41, C46(?) , etc should be investigated also. Would be rare to have a shorted speaker.

EDIT  :  Added a table listing voltages at the socket of 25L6

[image]

Comment: R18 is good. C36, C42 and C38 where all replaced with new capacitors. C30A, C30B, C30C and C30D, that were one "aluminum can" capacitor, where replaced with new electrolytic capacitors. R15, R19 and R20, which you read it as R30 due to the bad condition of the schematic, were all replaced with new resistors. I do receive a couple of stations on the "Broadcast" wave but both the reception and sound are weak. When I got this radio, the output transformer (T3) and the speaker both had been removed out from the radio so I had to scavenge other radios until I got them. C41 is new. I'll check C46.

Comment: If you haven't checked the voltages on the 25L6 tube socket, go http://www.nostalgiaair.org/  to find 4 page information on the radio. In addition to schematic, the socket voltages are given.  Pins 3,4,5, and 8 should be measured. I will add a portion of the document as an edit to my answer.  If the pin voltages measure normal, then your replacement T3 and speaker should be suspected as bad.

Comment: Thank you for the copy, I appreciate your help . I checked the voltages across the pins of all 5 tubes and here's what I'm getting: 25Z6 pin3 (205AC) / pin4 (231) / pin5 (205AC) / pin8 (231). 25L6: pin2 (42AC) / pin3 (205) / pin4 (131) / pin7 (17.6AC) / pin8 (10). 6SQ7: pin1 (0) / pin3 (0) / pin4 (-0.51) / pin6 (85.7) / pin7 (6.3AC) / pin8 (0). 6SG7: pin1 (0) / pin2 (11.6AC) / pin3 (0.8) / pin5 (0.8) / pin6 (89) / pin7 (17.5AC) / pin8 (143). 7Q7: pin 1 (11.5AC) / pin2 (142) / pin3 (106.8) / pin7 (0) / pin8 (5.3). I'll check C35 & C46, their values are listed in mfd but I think it should be pfd

Comment: regarding C35 & C46 : yes on the pf (it lists them as mica capacitors). Odd typo on parts list since old version of listing pf (pico-farad) was to use "mmf" (micro-micro-farad).  Voltages look normal.  Perhaps play the radio at low volume and see if the resistors self destruct (low cost with little at risk). You could measure the voltage across R25 and R24 (DC volts). Use voltmeter not oscilloscope. Then calculate current. The resistors do run HOT and is common failure in old radios.  Perhaps this has been an exercise in acknowledging that resistors do run hot to our senses, but is normal.

Comment: Signs of "too hot" are (1) the color bands change (!) and (2) smoke.  If not, they may be OK.  I also like that idea of checking *before* the tubes warm up--this helps isolate currents through the tubes from the other currents.  Filaments are in series, so pulling one tube would disable all filaments.

Comment: Once you get to C30A you have DC voltage.  Anything that you have to go through a resistor to get to, is an opportunity to measure the current.  Measure the voltage across R and solve E/R.

Comment: @Marla I was able to discover why R24 & R25 are heating-up, the culprit is the new output transformer T3 as Marla had pointed. Initially, when I got this radio, the output transformer (T3) and the speaker both had been removed out from the radio so I had to scavenge other radios until I got them. As per the schematic, T3 has 2 input wires but the one that I installed has 3  input wires but I did get sound from the radio when I connected two wires only and I didn't know where to connect the 3rd wire of the output transformer so I left unconnected.

Comment: When I disconnected T3, R24 & R25 are not heating up anymore.

Comment: T3 disconnect doesn't prove T3 is bad, but is a good step. By disconnecting T3, you also disconnected the output tube. Try running with T3 but at minimum volume. At minimum volume, only tube bias current flows. If heating persists, then problem with tube bias current.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at a [25L6 datasheet](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dlmain/Datasheets-3/DSA-51972.pdf) the audio power amp output valve is rated in excess of 50ma (combining anode and screen grid currents). You can confirm this by looking at the voltage across the cathode resistor (R15, 180R) which may also be rather warm.

That will form the bulk of the HT current, the remainder of the valves will take a few ma each (limited by R18? which is 3.3K).

Taking 50mA as the HT current, I make the power consumption in those resistors about 0.4W split between them : they should run warm, not hot.

Two possible suspects could be:

1. excessive leakage current in the main reservoir cap, C30A. This may have died, or it may simply need re-forming (connection to a current-limited HT voltage until it's electrolysed a new insulating layer; you can measure and watch the leakage current drop as it re-forms). A higher power higher resistance replacement for these resistors is one relatively kind way to limit current for the duration. A few minutes should show some progress, after a few hours it should be down to a couple of ma or less.
2. Leaky C38, pulling the 25L6 grid positive. This would be accompanied by a cherry red glow on the anode (plate) of the output valve.

Comment: Both capacitors, C30A and C38, are new capacitors. I checked the capacitance of C30A and it's 43.5mf, which is within normal range for a 40mf capacitor. As for the 25L6 tube, the plate glow is a dim orange color so I don't think that capacitor C38 is the suspect.

Comment: Still, worth measuring the grid and cathode voltages on the output valve.

Answer (score 1):

Vacuum tubes operate at very high voltages, usually on the order of hundreds of volts.  Take, for example, a 12AX7, which requires around 300V to operate.

Since you haven't posted the schematic for this circuit, I'm going to assume the worst-case scenario, which is that you're applying 300V across a 270 ohm, 2 watt resistor.

Since *V = IR* and *P = IV*, and therefore *P = (V^2)/R*, we can calculate the total power dissipated by your resistor by solving for P when P = (300v^2)/270ohms.  This gives us P = 333 watts.  I had to run this calculation twice to verify.  You're attempting to run somewhere on the order of 100 times as much power through your resistors as they were designed to handle.  This is true even if I'm off by a lot on my estimation of 300v.

Your 270 ohm, 2 watt resistor has a maximum current and voltage that it can safely endure without burning up.  The maximum voltage it can sustain without burning up can be determined by solving P = (V^2)/R for V.  So let's rearrange this to V = Sqrt(P*R), or V = Sqrt(2W * 270ohm), which solves to V = 23.2V.

I'm not aware of any vacuum tube that operates at a voltage that low, so assuming all of the values you've provided are accurate, it's no wonder your resistors are getting hot.

Either the resistance values you've picked out are not correct, or they're not rated high enough.  Frankly, I'm betting that you have your resistance values wrong.  Usually, valves (tubes) are biased using resistors in the kilo-ohm range.  I can't say I've ever seen a resistor that can dissipate over 300 watts by itself.

Please stop and verify that you have the correct schematic, the correct components, that you're reading the schematic correctly, etc. before you set something on fire.

**EDIT: Now that you've posted the schematics, this answer is obsolete.**

Comment: I have the schematics and I've bought both resistors exactly as per the schematics. The voltage applied across the resistors is 230 V as they are installed between the main power and the rectifier tube. When I removed the old resistor and checked it on the multi meter the value was 330 ohms exactly as the schematics but I decided to put a new resistor since the old resistor had some cracks on both ends .

Comment: The resistors don't have 300V or 230V *across* them. You're both assuming the voltage drops to zero at the rectifier, which doesn't make sense. You would need to know the current drawn by the radio, which will be well under 100mA, or P <= 1.5W, which makes much more sense. But I suspect the resistors are in the wrong place.

Comment: I've just attached the 1st page of the radio's schematics. As per the schematics,they directly connected to the 230 V line coming out of the transformer. Moreover, I installed them in place of the old resistors so I don't think that there is a mistake in there place or value. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: This radio is 100 Watts / 230 Volts so I think the current would be  around 450 mA.

Comment: 100W RF output, but you have to remember that a class AB2 circuit (as this most certainly is) only has about 50-60% efficiency.  So with 100W output that's a total of (100/0.6) = 167W at least.  Probably more like 200W being drawn.

Comment: So current at more like 900mA

Comment: You know, you can always just let the thing run until something blows up.  Most resistors fail open, so if they blow up due to overheating it will just shut off the HV to the tubes, saving the tubes.

Comment: This radio is more like 10 watts maximum *output*. @Daniel It is not class AB2, it is a class A SET, which is at best 12.5% efficient, so it might draw 100mA absolute tops, probably half that. Most of the current draw will be to the heaters, which don't go through these resistors. That would probably account for the rest of the missing 100W, which is undoubtedly the *input* power consumption.

Comment: He never stated input, so I auto assumed 100W output (ham radio standard).  Sorry...

Comment: Next time, post the schematics from the start.  It's a waste of peoples' time trying to guess at what you have.

Comment: Your edits to the question have also made this answer obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

The 25Z6GT is a dual rectifier tube that is rated for a maximum DC output current of 75 ma.  If it was putting out the maximum of 75 ma than the dissipation in the 270 ohm resistor would be 1.52 watts and the dissipation in the 330 ohm resistor would be 1.86 watts.  Assuming it is running somewhat less than maximum, say 50 ma, the respective dissipations would be 0.68 and 0.83 watts These numbers are consistent with a 2 watt resistor rating.  If the resistors are overheating, then the current is too large which means something in the radio is drawing too much current. As a start, I suggest replacing each tube with its original, one at a time, to see if one of your new tubes is defective.

Comment: Can you explain these dissipation calculations? I can only reproduce them by assuming a constant 75mA in each resistor, i.e. a total of 150mA.